# Loop over an array and image

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

I have links to my images and I have put them in an array. I would like to know how to loop my images using the existing links in my array. I would want something like this to show in smarty:

```
<img src="meat.jpg" />
<img src="chicken.jpg" />
<img src="pork.jpg" />
```

**This is my code now private**

```
$_arr = array(0 => "meat.jpg",
              1 => "chicken.jpg",
              2 => "pork.jpg"
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into [manual](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl) you simply need to pass `$_arr` to *Smarty* and use `foreach` loop like this:

```
{foreach from=$_arr item=src}
    <img src="{$src}"/>
{/foreach}
```